# How to estimate the pose of a dynamic cooperative and known object in space e.g in case of space debris?

Tags: robotic-arm, capture

I would like to know some novel approach, method or algorithm. The main purpose of pose estimation is to deal with the robotic capture in space

Comment: After reading the title a few times I think I understand part of it. There is an object, it is "known" and "dynamic cooperative", and you'd like to estimate it's [pose (computer vision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pose_(computer_vision)). So you have a series of images taken by the robot of a piece of space junk, and you would like to process them in order to compute the pose. I still can't figure out what "known" and "dynamic cooperative" really mean in this context. It would be great if you include a little more explanation. Robotics people may understand this but may readers here won't.

Comment: Just so you know, there are almost 200 Stack Exchange sites! There is a [robotics SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) and I've added a link to your question in their chat room. Also see all the helpful answers to [Stack Exchange site to ask questions about computer vision?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2794/163067)

Comment: Sorry, you need to make this question much clearer instaed of letting us guess what you mean.